# Media Query with Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

Situation: I have an image and two buttons below the image all of which are the same width.

Problem: If the viewport is too long horizontally you cannot see the buttons without scrolling down. This is a problem for tablets and small laptops. My current CSS looks like this:

```
 .image{
        width:90%;
        height: 50%;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 250px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }


    .buttonAnswer{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 500px;
        font-size: 25px;
```

I'm trying to find a way using media query's or something else to shrink both the buttons and the image down to a size where you can see both without scrolling on any size device.

It's a bit hard to give an example of the problem. View below and then shrink the viewport down to a narrow height and long width and you should see that you can only see the image and have to scroll to view the buttons.

```css
  .image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.buttonAnswer {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 25px;
```

```html
<img class='image center-block' id='image2' src='https://i.imgur.com/AMTXZ2R.jpg' alt="Girl trying to get a job">
<button id='stepOneYes2' type="button" class='buttonsQuestion2 btn btn-info center-block buttonAnswer buttonSpace'> Yes </button>
<button id='stepOneNo2' type="button" class='buttonsQuestion2 btn btn-info center-block buttonAnswer'> No </button>
```

Comment: is the image and buttons the only thing on the page? or  will there be anything else? There are many ways you could solve this, you can use media queries with height, or use the `vh` unit with height property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think that using media queries is a correct method to solve your problem. You would need to define another size for the image (especially the max-width) for your image on the critical viewports.

But you could also use viewport units for defining the size of your image. Right now you've set a fixed max-width, but that does not consider the size of the viewport. You could set it to 50 percent of the viewport height and change the other values accordingly:

```
 .image{
        max-height: 50vh;
    }
```

You can also combine both of the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max-height: 50vh` which means it will take 50% of any screen on which it will be displayed on.

```css
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  .outer {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
  .buttonAnswer {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 970px) {
  .outer {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .image {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
  .buttonAnswer {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p style="text-align:center"><img class='image center-block' id='image2' src='https://i.imgur.com/AMTXZ2R.jpg' alt="Girl trying to get a job"></p>
  <button id='stepOneYes2' type="button" class='buttonsQuestion2 btn btn-info center-block buttonAnswer buttonSpace'> Yes </button>
  <button id='stepOneNo2' type="button" class='buttonsQuestion2 btn btn-info center-block buttonAnswer'> No </button>
</div>
```